# SQL Lite 3 Supplying String as Seperate Characters?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Im trying to supply a 'Date Time' as a string formatted like this; *"2016-11-16 12:17:07.957850"*. SQL Lite is treating it as if I am passing each character in separately;

**sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 26 supplied.**

How do I fix?

```
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = """update Pet set [PastLogin] = @LastChecka where [PetId] = """ + str(PetID)

    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
    cursor.execute(sql,LastChecka)
    db.commit()
```

Comment: try this format `{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'}`.  Or if sqlilte supports it, use query parameters .

Answer (score 0):

The `execute()` function wants a list of parameters, and a string is a list of characters.

You must put the parameter into a tuple or array: `(LastChecka,)` or `[LastChecka]`

But it would be a better idea to use parameters for both values:

```
sql = "UPDATE Pet SET [PastLogin] = @LastChecka WHERE [PetId] = @PetID"
cursor.execute(sql, (LastChecka, PetID))
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't put any placeholders in your query at all. `@varname` refers to declared variables, not placeholders.

Note also that PetID should also be a parameter.

Also, wrapping field names in braces is not standard SQL.

```
sql = """update Pet set PastLogin = ? where PetId = ?"""
cursor.execute(sql,(LastChecka, PetId))
```